# Canceled chkdsk, chkdsk still runs

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, chkdsk

I was running a backup of a system on a drive and received the following error:

```
Failed to copy X:\AbraSuite\data\HRPERSNL.DBF to B:\abrabackups\AbraSuite06.24.2013\HRPERSNL.DBF due to Error performing inpage operation
```

I was running chkdsk in Windows 7 on a 3TB Segate external usb 3.0 hdd drive that may-or-may-not have been the cause of the error above (the error doesn't specify which computer caused the error, and the two computers in question are connected via a mapped drive).

I read online that the error can sometimes be fixed by running chkdsk on the effected drive, and so I started running chkdsk on it.  It took a really long time, and so I clicked cancel...but when I look at the lights on the external drive, they're still flashing as if chkdsk is still running.  I'm quite terrified to turn off my machine at this point and I'm just letting it run.  Is there anyway to cancel this?

Comment: You should have allowed chkdsk to finish.  All you can do at this point is wait. I do hope you have a backup of the data because the type of error you recieved indicates hdd failure.

Comment: 20 minutes later . . . if it is chkdsk itself still running, which it probably is not, it would show up in the task manager.  if it isnt it could be the drive attempting its own fixes. and there are RARE cases where software glitching can occur that can cause a endless talking like this, it is very rare, and doesnt do any good to leave it working like that.  In those cases I have slammed the system off, and dealt with a single proper chkdsk after.  I certannly cant tell you TO do that, just that I have seen it. it did totally act like the system was hosed, but that time it just wasnt.

Comment: Then back up a few steps, if you were performing all this to begin with because there is some odd stuff or even  virus like thing running, I would certannly be gleeing over the resource monitor items to see if there is anything goofy going on.  Meaning I wouldn't just sit there while all hell was breaking loose :-)   just in case bailing out was a better option.

Comment: **UPDATE:** It finished up...I'm trying to back it up again, I'll let you know what happens

Comment: Okay it finished, the backup drive seems to be sound, and I plugged it into the computer directly to check the S.M.A.R.T. stats and it says that it's okay...